# $f(c)=P_1(p_1/p_0<c)$ is continuous w.r.t. $c$?

Tags: probability, continuity

Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $P_1$ and $P_0$ be two distinct probability measure on it, having densities $p_1$, $p_0$ with respect to $\mu$. Can we prove $f(c)=P_1(p_1/p_0<c)$ is continuous w.r.t. $c$?

If cannot prove the continuity, can we make any assumption about $p_1$ and $p_0$, so that the continuity of $f(c)$ follows.

Comment: $p_{i}$ are densities? Also you probaboly mean that $P_{1}$ is the "law" and that $F_{1}( x )=P_{1}(X_{1} \in (-\infty,x))$

Comment: Furthermore I dont think one outs densities into a measure. Where did you find this problem? Can you just post a picture of it from the book it is in or something?

Comment: Do you mean probability $\Pr\{p_1(X_1) / p_0(X_0) < c\}$ instead? Note that a CDF is continuous if there is no point mass. So you merely need to argue that $p_1(X_1) / p_0(X_0)$ is a continuous random variable, which is true by your assumption.

Comment: I rewrite my question, i think its clearer this time. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @Maltus Correct, i encountered this problem when i was reading a paper. [A robust version of the probability ratio test, Huber]

Comment: @BGM Thanks for your comment! However, even if $p_1/p_0$ is continuous, i dont think the continuity of $f(c)$ holds.